# How can I password protect localstorage data?

Tags: javascript, security, local-storage, aes

Localstorage is stored without any protection.  Web apps are becoming less dependant on servers.

How can an app which uses localstorage for data store it so that a password is required to read it.

Comment: Why would you need to password protect localStorage?

Comment: You can use localstorage to cache data.  It might be to some extent confidential.  Or it could be used for something like a diary, or store an API key, or just a notepad-like application that you want to offer password protection for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passwords on servers usually work by using a hash like SHA1 or SHA512.  When the server receives a request with a password, it hashes that, and compares them.  If they match, the server loads some data, processes it, and sends it back to the user.  If we tried to do this with client-side JavaScript, we would have to already have the plain text available.

An alternative to hashing is a cipher, such as AES.  There's a [crypto-js library](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) on Google which provides services like these.  The stand-alone minified AES file is about 13kb before gzip.

One limitation of the library is JSON serialization of the AES data.  Their [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Output), does provide a solution to this.

<sup>Note: this doesn't JSON encode your object, it JSON encodes the data needed to decrypt your object (except the password, of course).</sup>

```
var JsonFormatter = {
    stringify: function (cipherParams) {
        var jsonObj = {ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)};
        if (cipherParams.iv) {jsonObj.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();}
        if (cipherParams.salt) {jsonObj.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();}
        return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    },

    parse: function (jsonStr) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
            ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(jsonObj.ct)
        });
        if (jsonObj.iv) {cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.iv)}
        if (jsonObj.s) {cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.s)}
        return cipherParams;
    }
};
```

To store data, we could do this

```
var encoded = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), password, {format: JsonFormatter}).ciphertext.toString();
localStorage.setItem("secret_stuff", encoded);
```

To get it back, we can do:

```
var stored = localStorage.getItem("secret_stuff");
var jsonString = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(stored, password, {formatter: JsonFormatter}).toString();
var secretObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

---

It might also be wise to "forget" the user's password if they haven't moved the mouse in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi @FakeRainBrigand, Thanks for the method. But somehow it does not work. Could you please make necessary changes?

Comment: I can't figure out why it's not working now.  I'm sure it worked at the time, and there's only been a couple commits since then.  If you can find a build of 3.1.0 or 3.0.1, try with that.

Comment: I used http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html and it seems working fine now.